# Проблема с отправкой сообщения web-сервису

Tags: java, spring, веб-служба

При отправке запроса на web-сервис через программу SoapUI запрос успешно проходит и возвращает корректный ответ. Если же отправляю запрос программно (java+spring), то отваливается с ошибкой:

```
    org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory$GenericSWSClient.invokeService(SpringWSClientFactory.java:224) ~[adapters-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory$GenericSWSClient.invoke(SpringWSClientFactory.java:163) ~[adapters-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at $Proxy329.request(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.impl.CRegistryRawXmlAdapter.submitImportOrgStructureRequest(CRegistryRawXmlAdapter.java:88) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.container.dto.ExtendedAdapterDto.invokeMethod(ExtendedAdapterDto.java:66) [adapters-container-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.TaskProcessor.invokeAdapterMethod(TaskProcessor.java:796) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.TaskProcessor.processOutgoingTask(TaskProcessor.java:420) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.DelayedOutgoingTaskExecutor.run(DelayedOutgoingTaskExecutor.java:137) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]

    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:157) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:112) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:120) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:654) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:603) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
```

Настройка web-сервиса:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.rawxml.wsclient" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="crRawXmlServiceClient" class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory"
          factory-method="createClient">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Class"
                         value="ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.rawxml.wsclient.RegistryUpdatePort" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="crRawXmlServiceTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="crRawXmlServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" />
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SXMessageSender">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="${http.proxy.host}" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="${http.proxy.port}" />
                <property name="channel" value="SMEV" />
                <property name="readTimeout" value="24000000" />
                <property name="connectionTimeout" value="24000000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="destinationProvider" ref="destinationProvider" />
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="wsSecHandler" />
                <ref bean="soapSigner" />
                <ref bean="soapLogger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="destinationProvider" class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.OutgoingServiceDestinationProvider">
        <property name="defaultUri" value="${cregistry.rawxml.ws.url}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Беглое гугленье советует таймаут соединения в настройках сервера уменьшить до 1-2 минут...

Comment: Не помогло. Ошибка та же